# Should I say 'for all sets of tasks' or 'for all sets of task'?

Tags: grammatical-number

In general, should it read either as:

1. all sets that are collections of individual tasks
   or
2. all sets of a task kind ?

In the first case I would expect 'task' to be plural, in the second case I would expect it as singular.

Comment: As "task" is countable and "set" implies many items, the singular is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

> For all sets of tasks

...is correct.

> For all sets of task

...is always incorrect.

Since "task" and "job" are similar enough, a substitution helps to show the error.  Incorrect:

> For all sets of job

Answer (score -2):

A "task" is singular, whereas a "set" is a collection of tasks (according to your question) - 'for all sets of tasks' would suit sets containing tasks, 'for all sets of task' would need a task defined.

Comment: This neglects to specify _which_ assumption is correct.

Comment: "Sets of task" is incorrect.  Excepting for words that are both plural and singular, (e..g. "bread" -- "loaves of bread" _never_ "loaves of breads"), the specific noun must be pluralized.